# Does encoding matter when writing to a file?

Tags: encoding

I was told today that when writing to a file the Encoding in which you write in doesn't matter. I don't know a lot about Encoding but this sounds reasonable considering Encoding is only for reading/viewing?

Does the Encoding in which bytes are read from a file matter? Is the Encoding there only for parsing/display?

ex.

```
var bytes = getFileBytes();
bytes.remove(new byte[] { 232, 211 });
anotherStream.writeBytes(bytes);
// I'm assuming that Encoding is irrelevant
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How important is file encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240916/how-important-is-file-encoding)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think somebody might have told you is that if you have to choose between encodings, it doesn't matter which one you pick *as long as you stick to it*.

This obviously ignores issues like the efficiency of the encoding (if one of them stores your typical data in fewer bytes, obviously use that then).

Consider the opposite scenario - you could write in one encoding and then either (a) forget about ever reading the data back in or (b) read the data incorrectly.

To use a contrived example, let's say you cannot use the letter lowercase `i` in your data file for some reason. So to store that, you need to encode it somehow. You decide to store it as `\48`. But now, how do you represent the literal sequence `\48` unambiguously, should you ever need to? Ah ha, your encoding can accommodate that, too: store any literal backslash as `\5C`. But of course, when you read the file back in, you have to decode this encoding, or you will end up with the wrong bytes. (ThÁ&s Á&s more common than you may thÁ&nk!)

Answer (score 1):

Encoding does not matter when you are simply reading *bytes* from the file and are not trying to *interpret* these bytes as *text*. For example, you can safely ignore encoding if you want to, say, copy a file to another file or a file to a socket. Obviously, you also don't need an encoding if the stream contains *binary* data, e.g. a sequence of `int`s in binary form. Your example is also perfectly valid, unless you do not understand `232` and `211` bytes as characters.

However, when you start *interpreting* some file (or any sequence of bytes, e.g. byte array) as *text*, you just *can't* ignore encoding, because bytes can be converted to characters *only* by the means of some encoding. Sure, it is usually possible not to specify an encoding when using something like `FileReader`, however, in this case the encoding is specified implicitly, usually with your locale encoding as a default. Because of this it is better to *always* specify the encoding you intend to use when loading character data from byte streams (e.g. via `InputStreamReader`), so the actual encoding would not depend on the system you're running your program on.